# SSIS - Input same number for a batch of records

Tags: sql-server, ssis, batch-processing

There is a Daily Load table with fresh daily data that needs to be transferred onto a Historical Table.

The Historical table has a extra column 'CSV_ID' that identifies the daily batch of records. For example, 10 records from the Daily table get transferred to the Historical Table today. All these 10 records will have a CSV_ID of 1. The batch for the following day will have 2 as its CSV_ID.

Do I use a derived column with an expression CSV_ID == " "? 1: CSV_ID + 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question is: "I have a table where `CSV_ID` for new records is empty and I want to set it as Next Batch Number....?"

There are several options to do that:
1. Use the approach you think of, but instead of `CSV_ID + 1` you better get the `MAX` value first and then just apply `MAX+1` for empty ones.
2. Load data `as is` and then apply `MAX+1` to the empty ones like this:

```
UPDATE MyStagingTable 
SET CSV_ID = (SELECT MAX(CSV_ID)+1 FROM MyStagingTable)
WHERE CSV_ID = '';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get an error saying Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: It was with the brackets. Now the error message states Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: This statement worked: 
UPDATE [his].[ContractorHistoricalLoad]
SET CSV_ID = (Select Max(CSV_ID) + 1 FROM [his].[ContractorHistoricalLoad])
WHERE CSV_ID IS NULL;